# how to auto increment project version number on VS 2012

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I searched for auto incrementing version number and found some solutions but I wonder which one is the most efficient and recent way? I do not know if there is a new feature or tool on Visual Studio 2012.

1st:
   changing AssemblyInfo.cs file

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")]
```

2nd: 
    [codeplex](http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/) (I don't know if it is compatible on VS2012)

3rd:
   Project properties under Publish

[image: Here]

4th:
  [Using T4 templates to manage assembly version information](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/vagif/archive/2010/04/24/using-t4-templates-to-manage-assembly-version-information.aspx)

Please suggest any other solutions or share your experience about versioning?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install AssemblyInfoTask
   You need to get this custom build task. Chris references the original source at gotdotnet.com which does not exist anymore. Either search for the text AssemblyInfoTaskvers with google or try this link
   http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AssemblyInfoTaskvers/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=232

   It should redirect you to the download area on MSDN where you can get the lates setup release.
2. Import the task into your build project
   Open Source Control in Visual Studio and make sure you have a local copy of the build project in your workspace. Then check out the TFSBuild.proj file (Unchanged, keep any existing lock) and open it. Add the following line right after the import of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets:

   ```
   <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)¥Microsoft¥AssemblyInfoTask¥Microsoft.VersionNumber.Targets"/>
   ```
3. Use a custom task for retrieving the revision number
   Each buildnumber contains a revision: FooBar_20090128.3 What we want to do is using this revision number also as revision in our Assembly version. So we need to implement a custom build task that is able to extract the revision number from the buildnumber so that we can assign it to the Assemblys' revision number. At the end of this article, I will post the sources you will need.
   Right after the import statement from above, register this custom build task by adding the following line:

   ```
    <UsingTask TaskName="ExtractRevision.ExtractRevisionTask" AssemblyFile="ExtractRevision.dll"/>
   ```
4. To configure all assembly properties and format the number formats respectively, add the following lines to your project file:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
   <!– Assembly version properties. Add others here –>
   <AssemblyMajorVersion>4</AssemblyMajorVersion>
   <AssemblyMinorVersion>0</AssemblyMinorVersion>
   <AssemblyBuildNumber>0</AssemblyBuildNumber>
   <AssemblyRevision>0</AssemblyRevision>

   <AssemblyFileMajorVersion>4</AssemblyFileMajorVersion>
   <AssemblyFileMinorVersion>0</AssemblyFileMinorVersion>
   <AssemblyFileBuildNumber>0</AssemblyFileBuildNumber>
   <AssemblyFileRevision>0</AssemblyFileRevision>


   <AssemblyBuildNumberType>DateString</AssemblyBuildNumberType>
   <AssemblyBuildNumberFormat>MMdd</AssemblyBuildNumberFormat>
   <AssemblyRevisionType>NoIncrement</AssemblyRevisionType>
   <AssemblyRevisionFormat>0</AssemblyRevisionFormat>

   <AssemblyFileBuildNumberType>DateString</AssemblyFileBuildNumberType>
   <AssemblyFileBuildNumberFormat>MMdd</AssemblyFileBuildNumberFormat>
   <AssemblyFileRevisionType>NoIncrement</AssemblyFileRevisionType>
   <AssemblyFileRevisionFormat>0</AssemblyFileRevisionFormat>

   <!– Dump the TFS BuildNumber to the Assembly Comment Prop –>
   <AssemblyDescription>$(BuildNumber)</AssemblyDescription>

   <!– TF.exe –>
   <TF>&quot;$(TeamBuildRefPath)¥..¥tf.exe&quot;</TF>
   <!– AssemblyInfo file –>
   <AssemblyInfoSpec>AssemblyInfo.*</AssemblyInfoSpec>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
5. Set the revision number
   By altering the target CheckSettingsForEndToEndIteration, you can use the custom build task you have yet to implement for extracting the revision number from the buildnumber and add it to the assembly version:

   ```
   <!–for 2008 use the GetBuildProperties Task to get the BuildNumber –>
   <GetBuildProperties TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)" BuildUri="$(BuildUri)">
     <Output TaskParameter="BuildNumber" PropertyName="BuildNumber"></Output>
   </GetBuildProperties>

   <!–  extract the BuildRevision –>
   <ExtractRevisionTask BuildNumber="$(BuildNumber)">
     <Output TaskParameter="BuildRevision" PropertyName="BuildRevision" />
   </ExtractRevisionTask>

   <!–  update the AssemblyInfo Props –>
   <CreateProperty Value="$(BuildRevision)">
     <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="AssemblyRevision"/>
   </CreateProperty>
   <CreateProperty Value="$(BuildRevision)">
     <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="AssemblyFileRevision"/>
   </CreateProperty>

   <!–  just needed if you populate the AssemblyDescription  too like in the sample  –>
   <CreateProperty Value="$(BuildNumber)">
     <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="AssemblyDescription"/>
   </CreateProperty>
   ```
6. Check out and back in all AssemblyInfo.[cs|vb] files from your workspaces
   Before you can alter the AssemblyInfo files, you need to let Team Build check them out:

   ```
   <!– Set the AssemblyInfoFiles items dynamically –>
   <CreateItem Include="$(SolutionRoot)¥**¥$(AssemblyInfoSpec)">
     <Output ItemName="AssemblyInfoFiles" TaskParameter="Include" />
   </CreateItem>

   <Message Text="These AssemblyInfo.* files were found:"/>
   <Message Text ="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)"/>

   <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionRoot)"
   Command="$(TF) checkout &quot;@(AssemblyInfoFiles, '&quot; &quot;')&quot;"/>
   ```

   Right after the altered files have been compiled, you can check them back in:

   ```
   Command="$(TF) checkin /comment:&quot;Auto-Build: Version Update&quot; /noprompt /override:&quot;Auto-Build: Version Update&quot; &quot;@(AssemblyInfoFiles, '&quot; &quot;')&quot;"/>
   ```

   Just in case anything bad happens, there is a way of undoing the changes:

   ```
   <!– In case of Build failure, the AfterCompile target is not executed. Undo the changes –>
     <Target Name="BeforeOnBuildBreak" Condition="'$(IsDesktopBuild)'!='true'">
       <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionRoot)"
       Command="$(TF) undo /noprompt &quot;@(AssemblyInfoFiles, '&quot; &quot;')&quot;"/>
     </Target>
   ```
7. Implement the ExtractRevision custom build task
   Simply create a new C# library project with the following class (and add a strong name to it by signing it in the project properties):
       namespace ExtractRevision
       {
           using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
           using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

   ```
       public class ExtractRevisionTask : Task
       {
       public override bool Execute()
       {
           int indexOfDot = buildNumber.LastIndexOf(".");
           if (indexOfDot != -1 & indexOfDot != buildNumber.Length – 1)
           {
           buildRevision = buildNumber.Substring(indexOfDot + 1, buildNumber.Length – (indexOfDot + 1));
           }
           else
           {
           //there is no char following the dot or we can't find a dot
           buildRevision = "0″;
           }
           return true;
       }

       private string buildRevision;
       private string buildNumber;

       public string BuildNumber
       {
           set { buildNumber = value; }
       }

       [Output]
       public string BuildRevision
       {
           get { return buildRevision; }
       }
       }
   }
   ```

You need to check in the .dll file directly into your TeamBuildTypes folder on TFS.

External Link : http://devsid.blogspot.in/2010/06/automatically-increment-assemblys.html

Comment: You should read the [help on answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the section **Provide context for links**.

Comment: Great, SO guidelines resulted in plagiarism. Wayback Machine might sometimes be a better convention than always including the (paraphrased) content in an answer.